# Use previous state of data

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to carry forward the previous state of data wherever data is not available. For example, I have following data;

| Month | Order | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item1 | 100 |
| 1 | Item2 | 200 |
| 1 | Item3 | 300 |
| 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Item4 | 100 |
| 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | Item1 | 100 |

So in the above example I want to use 1st month's information to be carry forwarded as it is for 2nd month. Also since 3rd month's information is available then use it for the month 4 and 5. Hence the output will be following:

| Month | Order | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item1 | 100 |
| 1 | Item2 | 200 |
| 1 | Item3 | 300 |
| 2 | Item1 | 100 |
| 2 | Item2 | 200 |
| 2 | Item3 | 300 |
| 3 | Item4 | 100 |
| 4 | Item4 | 100 |
| 5 | Item4 | 100 |
| 6 | Item1 | 100 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                Month, 
                MAX(CASE WHEN [Order] IS NOT NULL 
                         THEN Month 
                         END) OVER (ORDER BY Month 
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                             AND 1 PRECEDING) prev
         FROM test )
SELECT Month, [Order], Amount
FROM test
WHERE [Order] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.Month, t2.[Order], t2.Amount
FROM test t1
JOIN cte ON t1.Month = cte.Month
JOIN test t2 ON t2.Month = cte.prev
WHERE t1.[Order] IS NULL
ORDER BY Month, [Order];
```

[fiddle with some explanations](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0ad2d1329c0568ec5ca482e70593306)

Comment: Thanks a lot this works perfectly!